# JINJA creating xml files

Tags: python, jinja2

I am having issues creating xml files using JINJA. I am not using flask. this is just for creating the xml files.

```
env = Environment(FileSystemLoader(r'C:\Users\template\templates'))
template = env.get_template('template_fie.xml')

keeping my logic here and writing the values to a dictionary.

tempxmldata=template.render(values=values)
```

I am getting Error:

```
    template = env.get_template('template_file.xml')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 797, in _load_template
    raise TypeError('no loader for this environment specified')
TypeError: no loader for this environment specified
```

Can you pl let me know how I can get jinga using for xml file generation

Answer (score 0):

jinja2.Environment has multiple options in **init**, and loader isn't first position one

In order to make your code work you need only to set loader as keyword argument of Environment like this:

```
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(r'C:\Users\template\templates'))
```